# Are django model classes singletons/ only implemented once?

Tags: python, django

Are django model classes singletons/ only implemented once?  Such that

```
from .models import MODEL

# some code

a = MODEL

# in some other file
from .models import MODEL
# some code

b = MODEL

# some code

a is b # always True?
```

Comment: You're not instantiating any of the models (classes). This does not seem a valid way to demonstrate the behaviour of the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model classes themselves are not singletons and can be instantiated multiple times, but Python's import mechanism will only instantiate them once per import path; subsequent imports of the same module will copy references to the existing import.

TL;DR: Your code should work, barring weird import edge cases.